# Get the row (or column)-wise tabularized counts (as in table()) of a matrix

Tags: r, count

Given a matrix (or could be a data frame) with known distinct values (below it is 'a','b','c' and 'd') such as:

```
m<- matrix(c('a','b','a',
         'b','c','a',
         'b','a','a',
         'b','c','d'), nrow=4,byrow=T)

> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
[3,] "b"  "a"  "a" 
[4,] "b"  "c"  "d"
```

How can you get the counts (or column proportions) of values for each column (or row) and get the output of this into a (in this example) 4x3 matrix (or data frame) where first row is counts for 'a' in the columns of `m` etc.:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1    1    3
b    3    1    0
c    0    2    0
d    0    0    1
```

Was wondering if one can use some magic with apply(m,2,table)? Should say that `m`can be quite large (1e4 x 30) but number of distinct values always less than 40.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. How are those values derived?

Comment: Sorry folks, forgot byrow=T. Please see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We convert the matrix from wide to long using `melt` from `library(reshape2)` and then do the `table`

```
library(reshape2)
table(melt(m)[3:2])
#      Var2
#value 1 2 3
#   a 1 1 3
#   b 3 1 0
#   c 0 2 0
#   d 0 0 1
```

If we need the proportion, we can use `prop.table` and change the margin accordingly.

```
prop.table(table(melt(m)[3:2]),1)
```

Another convenient function is `mtabulate` from `library(qdapTools)`

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(as.data.frame(m)))
```

Comment: so simple and elegant! I believe this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Or use `table` and `col(m)`:

```
table(c(m),col(m))

#m   1 2 3
#  a 1 1 3
#  b 3 1 0
#  c 0 2 0
#  d 0 0 1
```

The `c(m)` vs `m` alone speeds things up dramatically with larger tables. This is competitive versus @akrun's solution:

```
m <- matrix(sample(letters[1:3], 5000*200, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000)
system.time(table(c(m),col(m)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.63    0.02    0.64 
system.time(table(melt(m)[3:2]))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.36    0.00    0.36
```